# Validate Property as [Required], but don't validate the value itself. Is it possible with Attributes and conventions in .net core 2 or higher?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
public class Post { 
     // ... other properties here

     public Author { get; set; } 
}

public class Author {
     // ... other properties here

    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

This is an overly-simplistic example. What I basically want is that the Author property in the Post class is never null, it MUST have a value. But because I'm pulling Author from a database, I am 100% sure that it's valid, so I want to skip the validation of the value of the Author property's value

In .net core 3 preview 9, recursive validation is causing unnecessarily long hold-ups where join entities for many-to-many relationships are involved.

I assume one workaround is to use [ValidateNever] in conjunction with the Validate() method just to check that the Author is not `null`. But I don't know if one of them will override the other.

But I am ideally looking to achieve this with Attributes and/or conventions

Answer (score 0):

You could write your custom validation attribute.When the value is null, it returns an Validation error.Otherwise, it returns `ValidationResult.Success`.

```
public class CustomRequiredAttribute :ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if(value != null)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            var propertyName = validationContext.DisplayName;
            var type = validationContext.ObjectType;

            return new ValidationResult("Could not be null for " + propertyName);

        }        
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Post { 
   // ... other properties here

   [CustomRequired]
   public Author { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: This has the unintended effect of changing the way that entity framework creates migrations and foreign keys. Specifically, in my case, it affected the foreign key columns by making delete actions 'restricted' while it was 'cascade' previously